# Cost of defining golang structs on function call

Tags: go, struct, type-declaration

I've stumbled upon a function that defines its own request and response types.

```
func doSomething() {

    type request struct {
        resourceID string
    }

    type response struct {
        resourceContents *Data
    }

    request := initializeRequest()
    result := dispatchRequest(request)

    ...
}
```

I think this has the great advantage of documenting the structure of the request and response right in the body of the function. The convenience of this is particularly evident when many such functions are in the same file and they all have a different type for their request and response structs: defining the types outside of the function means that I have to name them differently.

I'm concerned about the cost of this, though:
Is it much more expensive to have a function call declare its own type vs declaring that type in the package scope?

Also, is this approach idiomatic?

Comment: There is no extra cost. The definition is just scoped to the function, rather than to the package.

Comment: @Flimzy has it. Just to add some detail, Go is statically typed at compile time, meaning the type definition doesn't execute each time the function is called - it doesn't "execute" at all. It's only evaluated at compile time, it's just that if it's defined within a function that's the only place that type name can be referenced.

Comment: And if there would be a runtime cost (CPU or allocs): Write a benchmark and see if it hurts _your_ use case.

Comment: Really appreciate the quick answers, especially the "execution" metaphor!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Types are a compile-time concept and their scope won't (generally) affect runtime speed, since the code the compiler generates in these cases is oblivious to the original type (read up more on [Type erasure and reification](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2018/type-erasure-and-reification/)), with reflection being the outlier, but you have no reflection here.

---

That said, I find this code a bit suspicious:

```
request := initializeRequest()
```

Where is `initializeRequest` defined? It has to be aware of the `request` type, so I assume it's internal to the function as well? Otherwise the code wouldn't compile. These considerations limit the utility of function-local structs in many cases, but if you do have everything local, I think it's a good practice to hide the types as much as possible.

In larger scale programs, the issue of testing will also come into play. How do you test types and functions working on them if they are hidden in scope?

Comment: Another limitation is that such types can't have methods (and by extension can't implement interfaces). That makes them literally just data types. I do use them all the time for one-off marshalling and unmarshalling.

Comment: Thanks for your observation, @Peter: it is precisely in the scope of marshalling and unmarshalling that I am using these types.